# Shading images in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, transparency

I had to reinstall latex yesterday, and it seems I upgraded from beamer 3.26 to 3.32
So far I used a little piece of code to shade my images, in order to have them behave like for example lists do in transparent mode --- Everything that is yet to come is shown with an opacity of 15%
This worked really nicely, however it stopped working and I don't know if this is a bug, or due to some added features.
As far as I can make out beamer still doesn't provide this out of the box, so some kind of fiddling is necessary.
The question now is, how to get this to work again (short of downgrading beamer)
as can be seen from the image (and from my (overly complicated) files) it sometimes works, but not correctly.

- The image is uncovered in frame 2, even though it should be uncovered in frame 3 (I only attached frame 1)
- Further images are not shaded at all

This worked fine before (and was most useful together with \llap{} to superimpose tranparent pictures on top of other stuff

[image: result in 3.32]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includecoveredgraphics}[2][]{
    \ifthenelse{\the\beamer@coveringdepth=1}{
        \tikz
            \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.15]
                {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
    }{
        \tikz
            \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
                {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};%
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First point.
\item Second point.
\item Third point.\includecoveredgraphics[width=2cm]{test1}
\item Fourth Point \includecoveredgraphics[width=5cm]{test2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is the commit that broke your code: https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/commits/39bc573c5bfc03fbd23ea3c16c420abfb6cf3d9b If you comment out those lines in beamerbaseoverlay.sty your MWE will work fine again. This should be reported to the beamer mantainer, I assume.

Comment: Yes, commenting those lines out indeed restores my files.
May I ask how you knew that it was that particular part of code (as in: could I have found that out myself?)

Comment: I tested your code with version 3.31 and it worked fine, since there were only three commits between 3.31 and 3.32 and the other two were about totally unrelated stuff, I tried commenting out that commit and it worked. However please note that **this is not the proper solution**, as I said this should be reported (or maybe someone with a deeper knowledge will come up with a proper solution).

Comment: I am aware of that, and wanted to append my comment, but I was too slow.
Joseph Wright is quite active here, if he doesn't see this in a reasonable amount of time I'll file a bug-report (for a hack that stopped working, which to me seems a bit over the top)

Comment: I think I see the issue: `\tikz` uses `\endtikzpicture` internally without the grouping that really should be present (as `\endtikzpicture` is what is supposed to be used for `\end{picture}`). Solution at the `beamer` end is I think doable, although arguably this is a not-so-great approach by TikZ.

Comment: @JosephWright For inline uses, `\tikz` does stop parsing after the first occurence of `;` if the content is not *braced*.

Comment: @percusse Yes I know, but it does use `\endtikzpicture` internally: the problem (for me) is that I've assumed I can treat this as a grouped-and-paired command at a LaTeX level. I'll address that by checking `\@currenvir`, which will only be `tikzpicture` in the 'environment' form.

Comment: I've fixed this in the development version: do you need an urgent CTAN update?

Comment: YES please update :) It's an annoying bug.

Comment: @JosephWright Is it possible to update beamer ASAP ? Please, this bug breaks many slideshows.

Comment: @Xoff There is another bug in the database concerning this business: I'll see if I can sort it later today then think about the best plan. Either way, there should be a CTAN update by tomorrow.

Comment: This is fixed in `beamer` now, which makes the question 'off topic' ('Fixed by updating').